# how to use multiple language in ext mobile application?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a simple mobile app with some text content.

Now I m using button labels all directly like 
**`title: "App Title",`**
I want to develop multiple language support for this app.

i have tried create one language file

```
Ext.define('App.Language', {    
singleton   : true,

EN      :
{       
    Apptitle : 'App Title'

},
DE :
{
    Apptitle : 'Other lang title'
}
getLanguageData : function()
{     
    switch(App.config.App_language)
    {
        case 'en':
            return Language.EN;
            break;
            case 'tm':
            return Language.DE;
            break;
        default:
            return Language.EN;
            break;
    }

}
});
```

By default now in EN so i have set to launch function

```
 launch : function() 
 {
  App.Config.App_Language = 'EN';
  }
```

App.config.js

```
App_Language : null;
```

Now i want to call Apptitle like that

```
title : App.Language.getLanguageData().Apptitle,
```

when i tring i m getting error getLanguageData is not a function 
how to use any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate the same in sencha fiddle, it seems working fine. You can check below url - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/33vs

Also please make sure that that file in loaded successfully, may be that App.Language file is not loaded successfully thats why function was undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax may be wrong, add a comma before the `getLanguagedata` function.